# Why does my code fail with CStatic control not a window

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a modeless license dialog inside an another dialog. License dialog has a CStatic control. Initially I load a default picture for it:

```
void License::LoadPngPicturesFromResources(UINT defaultPictureId, UINT pictureWithHoveredLicenseId)
{
    ASSERT(defaultPictureId);
    m_pictureControl = static_cast<CStatic*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_LICENSE));
    ASSERT(m_pictureControl);
    m_pictureControl->ModifyStyle(SS_TYPEMASK, SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_REALSIZECONTROL);

    CRect rect;
    m_pictureControl->GetClientRect(rect);
    bool success = GraphicsUtils::LoadScaledPng(m_defaultPicture, defaultPictureId, rect);
    ASSERT(success);
    m_pictureControl->SetBitmap(m_defaultPicture);
    success = GraphicsUtils::LoadScaledPng(m_pictureWithHoveredLicense, pictureWithHoveredLicenseId, rect);
    ASSERT(success);
}
```

At this point there are no failed assertions and the picture is shown. However, when I try to change picture on mouse event, it breaks at line:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE HBITMAP CStatic::SetBitmap(HBITMAP hBitmap)
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (HBITMAP)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap); }
```

Here is how I change the picture:

```
void License::OnMouseMove(UINT flags, CPoint point)
{
    ASSERT(m_pictureControl);
    
    if (GraphicsUtils::PointIsInsideRect(point, m_licenseRect)) {
        if (!m_hoveredStateSet) {
            m_pictureControl->SetBitmap(m_pictureWithHoveredLicense); // Assertion failed
            m_state = State::License;
        }
    } else {
        m_state = State::Default;
    }
}
```

Here is my class definition:

```
class License : public Fragment
{
public:
    enum class State : uint8_t
    {
        Default,
        License
    };

    License(CWnd* parent, UINT templateId);

    void SetLicenseUrl(const TString& url);
    void SetLicenseRect(const CRect& rect);
    void LoadPngPicturesFromResources(UINT defaultPictureId, UINT pictureWithHoveredLicenseId = 0);

protected:
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(License)
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    void OnLButtonUp(UINT flags, CPoint point);
    BOOL OnSetCursor(CWnd* wnd, UINT hitTest, UINT message);
    void OnMouseMove(UINT flags, CPoint point);

private:

    CStatic* m_pictureControl = nullptr;
    TString  m_licenseUrl;
    CRect    m_licenseRect;
    CImage   m_defaultPicture;
    CImage   m_pictureWithHoveredLicense;
    bool     m_hoveredStateSet = false;
    State    m_state           = State::Default;
};
```

**Update:** thanks to IInspectable. The problem indeed is because of storing `GetDlgItem` result. I didn't read documentation for this method carefully. As of using `DDX` mechanism, I will consider it. Also, I've found this article [Avoiding GetDlgItem](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/537/Avoiding-GetDlgItem)

Comment: [Why do I get spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031001-00/?p=42343)

Comment: I read the article, but I don't understand what exactly worries you. Yes, it's better check for previous position of mouse, but in my case all messages delivered properly, thus I get the failed assertion.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're receiving a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message before wiring up the `m_pictureControl` class member with the control identified by `IDC_LICENSE`. I'm not entirely confident that the previously posted link applies. However, what you should be doing instead is taking advantage of [MFC's infrastructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn026-ddx-and-ddv-routines) to connect C++ classes to the native windows they represent: That is, call `DDX_Control` from your `DoDataExchange` override.

Comment: Having given this some more thought, the issue is probably down to what [`CWnd::GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getdlgitem) returns. There's guidance in the *"Return Value"* section that reads: *"The returned pointer may be temporary and shouldn't be stored for later use."* The code presented, however, does exactly that. It stores the value for later use.